# JS Angular constructor hydrate abstraction

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**JS FRAMEWORK/ LIBS:**

I'm using Angular 1.5.x and lodash 4.x.

**QUESTION:**

I'm new to JS and struggling with how to inject a new object instance into a abstracted function (ideally factory). Per my service class `FormService` I have a function creates the `FormModel`(object) and hydrates its constructor - `hydrateModel = function(arr)`. Is there anyway to abstract that to a generic function or factory class so that I can object a new generic object instance.

I can do this with backend languages but I'm struggling to make that type of syntax work with JS, which has me replicating the `hydrateModel` function for each data model instance (uGly). Said  differently how can I make a  OR ideally a . Appreciate any guidance. Ideally this makes sense and apologies if there is a basic answer.

**EDIT - IDEAL OUTCOME**

Would be to do something like this, which obviously doesn't work.

```
      hydrateModel = function(arr, varObjectInstance) {
            var newArr = [];
            _.each(arr, function (obj,k) {
               // is it possible in JS to inject a new object and reference it dynamically with a different set of dynamic arguments
                newArr.push( [varObjectInstance](obj, fillable));
            });

            return newArr;
        },

        hydrateModel(arr, new ObjectInstance())
```

Example, in PHP you could say `new $var($arguments)`

**REFERENCE CODE CONTEXT**

```
// note I've removed the __constructor for brevity sake but it is a fairly basic object extend class

FormModel.$inject = ['__constructor', 'object'];
function FormModel(__constructor, object) {
    function Form(data, keys) {
        __constructor.call(this, data, keys);
    }

    Form.prototype = Object.create(__constructor.prototype);
    Form.prototype.constructor = Form;
    return Form;
}

FormService.$inject = ['FormModel', 'FormDataService'];
function FormService(FormModel,FormDataService) {
    var service = this,
        forms = {},
        fillable = ['app_id','name','class','label','type','maxlength','minlength','placeholder','required','autocomplete','index','helpTitle','helpDescription','messages'],
        hydrateModel = function(arr) {
            var formEloquent = [];
            _.each(arr, function (obj,k) {
                formEloquent.push( new FormModel(obj, fillable));
            });

            return formEloquent;
        };

   // INIT function: 1. get form field (email, name, password,etc) data for 3 forms along with help messages etc.
    service.initForms = function () {
        var self = this;
        _.each({
            register:FormDataService.getRegisterData(), // not including FormDataService for brevity sake but it is  http api service to backend
            contact:FormDataService.getContactData(),
            subscribe:FormDataService.getSubscribeData()
        }, function (obj, key) {
            forms[key] = {
                model:{},
                current:1,
               // below is my question - how could create a function / factory hydrateModel(obj, newGenericObjectInstance) that would be generic so that I can call new [newGenericObjectInstance](arguments) here or in the hydrateModel
                data:hydrateModel(obj),
                view:{},
                state:{},
                help:{}
            }
        });
    };

    return {
        initForms: function () {
            return service.initForms();
        }
    }
}
```

**DATA EXAMPLE**

Example of a form field data row returned from FormDataService (basic)

```
    var formFieldRowExample = {
        id: '1010',
        name: 'email',
        class: 'form--input',
        label: 'Enter your email',
        type: 'email',
        maxlength: 50,
        minlength: 4,
        placeholder: 'Example: person@example.com',
        required: true,
        autocomplete: 'on',
        validation: [
        {
            type: 'email',
            message: 'Email must be a valid email address'
        },
        {
            type: 'minlength',
            message: 'Your email address is too short'
        },
        {
            type: 'maxlength',
            message: 'Your email address is too long'
        },
        {
            type: 'required',
            message: 'Your email address is required'
        }
    ]
    };
```

Comment: The question lacks really simple explanation what exactly you need. 'CODE' is overladen with details, and 'IDEAL OUTCOME' doesn't make it any clearer. I'm quite sure that the answer would be a couple of lines of code, just not sure what the question is.

Comment: @estus thanks for suggestion. I've adjusted the ideal outcome to simplify. I tend to add all the content as often people ask for reason or context. In summary I trying to determine if I can inject new object instance into a function and then reference it dynamically with a different set of arguments

Answer (score 0):

In the example above `varObjectInstance` is an object, not constructor function. It cannot be called or `new`ed.

The workable code may look like this

```
  hydrateModel = function(arr, Cls) {
    var newArr = [];
    ...
    newArr.push(new Cls(obj, fillable));
    ...
  }

  hydrateModel(arr, ObjectInstance)
```